# How to find all occurences of substring in string, in python

Tags: python, string, find

I need help explaining how this solution I found on stack overflow works. Why if k = -1, do you need to return positions. If I change it to return anything else, it does not work. Thank you.

```
def findSubstring(sequence, substring):
    positions = []
    k = 0
    while k < len(sequence):
        k = sequence.find(substring, k)
    if k == -1:
        return positions
    else:
        positions.append(k)
        k += 1 #change to k += len(sub) to not search overlapping results
print(positions)
```

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 0):

`str.find()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the substring (if found). If not found, it returns -1.

This is what happens in the `findSubstring` function:

- First, an empty list is created to later add the indexes of occurrence of the substring.
- `while k < len(sequence)`: we want to look for the substring until we get to the last index of the sequence.
- `k = sequence.find(substring, k)`: we assgin the index of the first occurrence of the substring after index k (which for the first iteration should be the beginning of the sequence and that's the reason for setting `k=0` before the while statement.)
- Now, if the substring wasn't in the sequence `k=-1` and else the index which the substring occurred.
- `if k == -1: return(positions)`: if the substring isn't found, `k=-1` and the empty `positions` list is returned, otherwise the index, k, is appended to the `positions` and the `k +=1` will make sure that in the next iteration, we look for the substring starting after the index tha was just found.
- we iterate over k until we get to the end of the sequence (`while k len(sequence)`)
- `print(positions)`: the function returns the list of indexes and we print it in the end.